# How to check if warning banners have been created in a shell script

Tags: shell-script, banner

What are the commands needed to run a script showing warning banners have been created with if else statement?

Eg:

```
If [something == something]
   echo " Banners created"
else
   echo "Banners not created"
   echo " Details: "
   echo $( /bin/ls -l /etc/motd)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if grep -q 'mywarning' /etc/motd; then
    echo " Banners created"
else echo "Banners not created"
    echo " Details: $(/bin/ls -l /etc/motd)"
fi
```